# Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz after adding analytics

Tags: android, gradle, google-analytics, google-play-services

After I added google analytics I get this error, can't find a solution yet...

here is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.budiyev.android:circular-progress-bar:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.channguyen:adv:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.jetradarmobile:android-snowfall:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.github.Binary-Finery:Bungee:master-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5' //added this and got this error!

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 1):

`build.gradle` (Module:app) this code:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

and

`build.gradle` (Project:project) this code:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

this work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have used a libraries for Firebase with Google Analytics Services SDK for Android.
It says from the documentation, [Add Analytics to Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) that [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/) is the recommended method to track Android Apps. There's a service from Firebase library you can use.

```
Analytics   com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5
```

You can view [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions) the other latest versions of Firebase SDK for Android.

If you want to continue to use [Google Analytics Services SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), you can follow the guide from the documentation.